# Retrieve data from a collection(mongo),modify the returned object and insert it into another mongo collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
{
        "name" : "XYZ",
        "phone" : 12345,
        "emp_id" : 9999,
        "sal" : 5000
}
```

I want to add data on this record and store it into another database. I have tried this:

```
db=connection.testing

results=db.test.find({"name":"XYZ"})

for i in results:

    i.append('dept':'Marketing')
    db.test.insert_one(i) 

(please ignore the insertion being done on the same connection)

Error:    i.append('dept':'Marketing')

                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to add data in the dictionary form or JSON form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `i` in your example seems to be a dictionary, you most likely need something like `i.update({'dept': 'Marketing'})` or `i['dept']='Marketing'` in order to introduce new key/value pair